# docker-compose service can't auto start by systemctl after reboot

Tags: docker

After reboot only some service can start successfully. **I must start them manually**.

Some service can't and sth strange happen,
for example **database** service include mysql, redis, es, logstash ,etc but only es start a container, other container stop without error.

my docker version is 20.10

[image]

This is service config

```
[Unit]
Description=nginx
After=network.target
After=docker.service
After=communication.service
After=database.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose up
WorkingDirectory=xxx
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=15

StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I get error when start nginx.service after reboot. `Found ordering cycle on multi-user.target/stop`

[image]

Only I downgrade the docker version to 19.03.13, everything become ok.

But I don't what happen ?

Comment: Don't try to run `docker-compose up`  at startup, and don't try to manage Docker containers with systemd. If you want you containers to start automatically, just set an appropriate [restart policy](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#restart) on the container.

Comment: @larsks Why don't try to run `docker-compose up` ? I want my containers auto start in specific order so I use systemd.

Comment: `systemctl enable docker`, have you done it?

Comment: Docker already has the ability to manage the automatic startup of containers at system boot. You'll find your life easier if you use the right tool for the job. If your containers depend on a particular startup order, you have another problem to fix.

Comment: Try to daemonize it with -d

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram Yes Of course